# Using partial fractions in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I am trying to solve the following ODE via different methods as in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455939/solving-this-bernoulli-ode):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dr}{dt} &= ar(1-r) + b (1-r)^2
\end{align}
$$

The correct solution is given by:

$$
r(t) = \frac{e^{at} -1}{ e^{at} - 1 + (a/b)}
$$

In this part I try to use partial fractions. I have never used this method before and am quite unsure of how to proceed. My first step is to separate the equation. Here is my attempt:

$$
\int \frac{1}{ar(1-r) + b(1-r)^2} = \int dt 
$$

$$
= \int \bigg\{ \frac{1}{ar} + \frac{1}{a(1-r)}\bigg\}dr + 2\int \frac{1}{b(1-r)} dr
$$

Then,

$$
t = \frac 1 a \ln ( r(r-1)) - \frac 2b \ln (r-1) +c 
$$

Taking the exponential:

$$
e^{at} = r(r -1) + (r-1)^{-2a/b}
$$

I am not sure if this is correct, or how to proceed? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $s=r-1$.
$$\frac{1}{ar(1-r)+b(1-r)^2}=\frac{1}{bs^2-a(s+1)s}=\frac{1}{s((b-a)s-a)}$$
$$=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{(b-a)s-a}$$
which implies
$$A(b-a)s+Bs-aA=1$$
$$A(b-a)+B=0$$
$$aA=-1$$
That is
$$A=-\frac{1}{a}$$
$$B=-A(b-a)=\frac{b-a}{a}=\frac{b}{a}-1$$
Then you have
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=s((b-a)s-a)$$
$$\int\left(-\frac{1/a}{s}+\frac{b/a-1}{(b-a)s-a}\right)ds=\int dt$$
$$-\ln s+\ln \left(s-\frac{a}{b-a}\right)=at+K$$
$$\frac{1}{s}\left(s-\frac{a}{b-a}\right)=Ce^{at}$$
$$1-\frac{a}{(b-a)s}=Ce^{at}$$
$$\frac{a}{(b-a)(r-1)}=1-Ce^{at}$$
$$r=\frac{a}{(b-a)(1-Ce^{at})}+1$$

Comment: Wow thank you very much for a very insightful answer! :D

Comment: @RedPen You are welcome! BTW, what is your condition to determine $C$?